# Is $p^n\mid\binom{p^n}{k}$ true?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I already know that $p\mid\binom{p}{n}$ for $0< n<p$. I wonder if this is also true for $p^n$.

> Let $p$ be a prime and $n\geq 1$ be an integer. For integer $0<k<p^n$, $p^n\mid\binom{p^n}{k}$.

Is this true? The reason I ask this is because the context "if $\alpha$ is a root of an irreducible $f=x^{p^n}-x+1\in\Bbb F_p[x]$ then $\alpha+a$ for $a\in\Bbb F_{p^n}$ is also a root of $f$".

Comment: No, $4$ does not divide $\begin{pmatrix} 4 
\\ 2\end{pmatrix}=6$.

Comment: Also, $9$ does not divide $\binom{9}{3} = 84.$

Comment: How should I accept the context then?

Comment: $\Bbb F_{p^n}$ is not $\Bbb Z_{p^n}$.

Comment: Oh it's just follows by inductively applying $(x+y)^p = x^p+y^p$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us denote the maximum power of $p$ that divides an integer $n$ by $v_p(n)$.

Kummer's theorem tells us that $v_p(\binom{a}{b})$ is equal to the number of carries when performing base $p$ addition of $b$ and $a-b$.

In our case $a$ is $p^n$, which is $\underbrace{10\dots 0 }_{ n \text{ zeroes }}$, so when doing the addition there will be a a carry at each position that is not a trailing zero.

In other words $v_p(\binom{p^n}{k}$ is equal to $n$ minus the number of trailing zeros of $k$ in base $p$, or in other words $v_p(\binom{p^n}{k}) = n - v_p(k)$, so the claim in the title holds if and only if $p\nmid k$.

Answer (score 1):

Pascal's Triangle, row $2^2=4$ reads $ 1,4,\color{blue}{6},4,1$. We have only $p|\binom{p^n}{k}$.